# Can I post a picture to user's wall using only App Token?

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra, koala

I am developing a Facebook application using sinatra and Koala.
I'd like to know if it's possible to publish to user's wall (a picture, not just text) using only the App Token.

I have user's permissions but still get an error:

```rb
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new("MYAPPTOKEN")
@graph.put_picture("http://path.to/image", {:message => "ermargherd"}, user_facebook_id)
```

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError - OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource.
```

It's pretty simple to updte user's status, but how to put a picture?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the token is legit? Have you tested the permission you have with this user on the facebook graph explorer?

Comment: @oldergod, I'm quite sure because I can update the user's status, but anything beyond that, returns me an error.

Comment: there is different permissions for updating status and uploading pictures. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions

Comment: I think this is almost an answer @oldergod.

Comment: if that fixed your problem, I could write it as an answer so you could accept it.